# How to get the time difference between the start time and endtime having time transition from PM to AM?

Tags: php, datetime

I have the below code to calculate the time difference but when i run the code it prints 0 difference. Please see into my code below.

I want to get the time difference between the time interval which has Time Transition from PM (Today) to AM (Next day).

```
//echo 'Hello World!';

//echo mktime('11','30','0','1','2019','1');
//echo mktime('12','30','0','1','2019','1');

//echo ("  hello ");
//echo date(time());
//echo (" hello ");
//echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s A');

$date = "2019-10-16";
$stime = "11:30:00 PM";
$etime = "12:30:00 AM";

if("PM" == date('A', strtotime($stime)) && "AM" == date('A', strtotime($etime)))
{
  //echo " Time transition ";

  //get the start date and start time merging format
  $sdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s A', strtotime("$date $stime"));

  //convert the start datetime into epoch
  $startepoch = strtotime($sdatetime);

  //increment the date to get the next day date  
  $edate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 1 day'));

  //get the end date and end time merged
  $edatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s A', strtotime("$edate $etime"));

  //convert the end datetime into epoch
  $endepoch = strtotime($edatetime);

  $timediff = ($endepoch-$startepoch)/3600.0;

  echo " Time Difference: ".$timediff;


}else{

  echo "No time transition";

}



// 24 hour format
//$time = "00:00:00";

//echo date('A', strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP datetime and strtotime can parse times with AM and PM.
DateTime objects can also be compared directly.
If the end time is less than the start time, it is assumed to be the end time of the next day. This is better than selecting between AM and PM.

```
$date = "2019-10-16";
$stime = "11:30:00 PM";
$etime = "12:30:00 AM";

$dtStime = date_create($date." ".$stime);
$dtEtime = date_create($date." ".$etime);
if($dtEtime < $dtStime){
  $dtEtime->modify('+1 Day');
}
$diff = $dtStime->diff($dtEtime);
$seconds = $diff->h *3600 + $diff->i * 60 + $diff->s;

echo "Diff: ".$seconds." Seconds";
```

returns

```
Diff: 3600 Seconds
```